# How can I bind selecteditem value from combobox to textbox and save changed value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm making a simple Sales Managers.  I have list of products in a combobox with their default prices.

When I change the product, the price is displayed in a textbox and it's correct, because textbox is binding with Price property of SelectedProduct from combobox.

```
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stkSale" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Background ="LightSteelBlue"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbProducts" Height="30" Width="Auto" MinWidth="200" FontSize="17"  VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                  Margin="10,0,10,0"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListProducts}"  DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
                               >
                        </ComboBox>

                        <TextBox Name="txtSalePrice" BorderBrush="DarkBlue"   InputScope="Digits" Text="{Binding SelectedProduct.Price,  Mode=TwoWay}"
                     FontSize="17" FontWeight="ExtraLight" Height="30" Width="50" Margin="0,0,10,0"  />
```

Now I want to save this product in sales, for example with the changed price. However I don't know how I can bind this. When I will change Price in textbox it also change price of Product because of Mode=TwoWay.
What is good approach to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused, do you want new Product to be added to the list when you press the Add button?

Comment: After selecting a  record those values are reflected on text box now. when u change a the text box it has to automatically reflect on data grid right?

Comment: @TheLastStark I want to add new sale line with changed default price of selected product by pressing 'Add'

Comment: @AvinashReddy 
1. I'm selecting product from ComboBox.
2. Price is displayed in TextBox. (Product price, default for new sale line)
3. Now I want to save changed price in new sale line and display it in datagrid

Comment: @user3688227 Can u post the data grid code.

Comment: @user3688227 you can achieve this by binding a `Command` to the button and passing the text box values as `CommandParameter` or since the text box values are already bound to properties, you can handle it in the ViewModel itself by accessing the property bound to the text boxes.